# Does anyone know a good resource for statement of purpose critiques?

Tags: statement-of-purpose

I have been out of academia for about eight years and am looking to go back to graduate school. I would like to get some feedback on my statement of purpose, outside of the circle of friends and family I have available. Does anyone know a good resource I might be able to turn to. Thanks in advance!